# removing duplicate values in column

Tags: sql

there is a column called r_no which as three duplicate values associated with date column

```
r_no         date values
1            09-Apr-2016  03:49:24
1            09-Apr-2016 03:49:30 
1            09-Apr-2016 03:49:40
```

I want output as:

```
1 09-Apr-2016 03:49:40
```

removing duplicate values with latest date value

Comment: Edit our problem and put the data in using text format.  Put four spaces before each line so it looks like a table.

Comment: You want to remove duplicate data or Just show unique data ??

Comment: yes and with latest date value i.e 09-Apr-2016 03:49:40

Comment: whats wrong with current answer ??

Comment: it has to fetch the row with latest date value

Comment: That is exactly what the answer does

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that You're working with Microsoft `SQL Server` :

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, DATE FROM #TEMP ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Delete & show the latest :

```
;WITH TTT AS
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)SR, DATE, ID FROM #TEMP
) 

DELETE  FROM TTT WHERE DATE NOT IN(SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TTT)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

**Explanation:** The CTE will grab all of your records and apply a row number for each unique entry. Each additional entry will get an incrementing number.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified... At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for!

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete dublicate data](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-duplicate-rows-using-row-number-partition-by-order-by.aspx) directly from CTE expression where Row_Number() function is used as follows

```
;with cte as (
select 
    r_no, [date values],
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by r_no order by [date values] desc) as rn
from temptbl
)
delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT yt.r_no, oa.[date values]
FROM YourTable yt
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [date values]
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE r_no = yt.r_no
             ORDER BY [date values] DESC) oa
```

You can also do this with an embedded query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE [date values] = (SELECT MAX([date values]) FROM YourTable WHERE r_no = yt.r_no)
```